# How to customize add title logo to my beamer?

Tags: beamer

I'm want to make my conference presentation according to the given [view here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8dLB-bsLJ6pODltb2tDNmFROGc/view?usp=sharing) description. What should I add to my preamble and how what changes should I make to get the desired layout.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.7\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{.7\paperwidth}{}{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/read/dvzynzmdvcgf
Till now what I have done.

Comment: @kitty: Please do not post such Overleaf etc. links here. Most likely, you can reduce your document and post it here.

Comment: Can you please specify which elements you want to add/modify?

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: I want to  add yhe title frame as in the hyperlink